# Connection refused while launching docker containers using java client

Tags: java, docker

I 'am new to docker , I want to launch docker containers using java client ,

I tried https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java as below

```
package containers.launch_containers;

import com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient;
import com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder;

public class StartContainers{
     DockerClient dockerClient;

    public StartContainers() {
        startContainers();
    }

    public void startContainers() {
           try {

                dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance("tcp://127.0.0.1:2375").build();
                //starting the container of hello-world 
                dockerClient.startContainerCmd("hello-world").exec();


    }catch(Exception ex)
           {
             ex.printStackTrace();
           }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        StartContainers startContainers=new StartContainers();
    }   
}
```

with setting the required configurations in bashrc

> export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
>
> export DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H
>   unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

Docker Images in localhost

[image: dockerimages]

I have got this Exception

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   127.0.0.1:2375 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:481)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
>     at
>   com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:29)
>     at
>   com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:12)
>     at
>   com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.java:23)
>     at
>   com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:35)
>     at
>   com.github.dockerjava.core.command.StartContainerCmdImpl.exec(StartContainerCmdImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   containers.launch_containers.StartContainers.startContainers(StartContainers.java:18)
>     at
>   containers.launch_containers.StartContainers.(StartContainers.java:10)
>     at
>   containers.launch_containers.StartContainers.main(StartContainers.java:29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue , I should get Container Id as below

```
   dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance().build();
    //starting the container    
   CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd("hello-world")
           .withCmd()
           .exec();
   dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();
   //stop the container 
   dockerClient.stopContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();
```

reference

https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/wiki